# Нужен warning на сравнение size_t и unsigned int

Tags: c++

Можно ли как-то добиться, чтобы упомянутое сравнение вызывало warning ? То есть, чтобы код:

```
const size_t n = 100000;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    //...
}
```

выдавал warning ?

Comment: Компилятор какой?

Comment: пробовали на GCC и clang

Comment: `-Wconversion` не помог

Comment: Тогда наверное никак? Можно написать програмку на libclang, которая парсила бы код и искала такие конструкции.

Comment: Там  будет предупреждение если размер типа не совпадает, или же типы не совпадают, а так возможно они одинакого размера.

Comment: они разного размера, один 8 другой 4, я проверил

Comment: придумал только, чтобы запретить функциям использовать `int`, например так : `void operator[](unsigned int)=delete;` *проблема XY*

Comment: `for (decltype(n) i = 0; i < n; ++i)`

Comment: тогда уже `class Size` с операторами. @Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: От преобразования `unsigned int` в `size_t` данные не потеряются. А если нужны строгие типы, то пишите свой компаратор и проводите code review или вообще strong_typedef

Comment: @user7860670, если `n` будет очень велико, цикл не закончится никогда.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Если `n` будет очень велико, то можно получить предупреждение, что сравнение в условии будет всегда истинно.

Comment: @user7860670, если это константа доступная компилятору. Иначе - нет. Обидно, что тестирование этот код пройдёт наверняка, а зависнет когда начнёт обрабатывать большие наборы данных.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну тогда смотрите мой предпредыдущий комментарий.